# How can I use HTML tags as native tag into my ios application

Tags: html, uiwebview, uiscrollview, custom-controls

I have to make a custom control in which I have to format HTML tag into native tag. Suppose I write:

```
label.text = @"&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;Hello World&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;
```

Then it should print `Hello World` in bold and italic format. I have to do it in for general HTML tags like `&lt;p&gt;,&lt;br&gt;,&lt;u&gt;,&lt;a href&gt;,&lt;img&gt;` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a UIWebView (since you can just put HTML in there.)
You can make the background of a UIWebView transparent to make it integrate with your app better.

The alternative for displaying formatted text in IOS is with CoreText.
Apple has an example on how to use CoreText [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleTextInput/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: No problem.
Welcome to StackOverflow by the way.
If my answer was helpful, please upvote it, and if it solved your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: But I don't want to use UIWebView. If I have to display sum paragraph in non-editable UITextView and I wish it display some text in bold some text in italic and some text in different font size then how can I achieve it. Doing it in Object-C style will increase LOC.

Comment: Then your only way is to use CoreText. I posted a link to a coreText example.
You may need to parse the formatting and apply it from the source string yourself if you are going to use CoreText though.